# Open a popup on pageshow in Jquery-Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

It appears that I can't open a popup in a method called with the event "pageshow". I know that my code isn't wrong because the popup is opened when I click on the button... And I checked in Firebug there's no error messages. Here's the code :

HTML :

```
<div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
    ... my elements
</div>
```

JS :

```
$('#p_guarantee').live('pageshow', function(){
    $('#myPopup').popup('open');
});
```

Anybody knows if there's something special to do ? I would be soo grateful if you can solve my problem :)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: have you tried doing this on `pagechange` ?

Comment: if your popup div actually on a previously existing page BEFORE you change to a new one, or is it on the new page you're changing TO?

Comment: It's on the page I'm changing to !

Comment: there's one last thing that comes to my mind - try to do the popup function via `setTimeout()` and / or remove `data-role="popup"` from your popup div... if those don't help, I'm probably out of advices :)

Comment: Hum, that works with setTimeout("...", 100); but I don't think that's what we are supposed to do ! But until I find a better way that'll do the trick ! A huge thank your for your help :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following our discussion in comments, you can resolve this using `setTimeout()` function after the `pageChange` event is fired. I suspect this could be because the page is first rendered and improved and only after this, elements with special meanings (like popups) get their events bound.

You can also try to remove the `data-role="popup"` from your popup DIV completely and essentially do this:

```
<div id="myPopup">
    ... my elements
</div>

$('#p_guarantee').live('pagechange', function(){
    $('#myPopup').popup();
    $('#myPopup').popup('open');
});
```

... and see if that works for you.

Comment: I didn't try with the pageChange event, but for me that works with the pageshow event :) and there's one problem with your second solution : if you remove the "data-role" attribute, the content of the div will be shown in the page.

Comment: hmm, that data-role thingy seems strange, especially since I thought popup() would basically replace its functionality... but thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

I see no problems in your code. For which platform are you developing?

Try with the code in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/hhejq/1/

Comment: I'm developing for iPad but I tried on Firefox too and that doesn't change anything. Unfortunately your code doesn't work either :(

Comment: [Edit] Your code works, but only when I'm on the page and I refresh it, not when I come from another page. That's strange...

Comment: Try writing `$('.ui-page-active').trigger('create');` before invoking popup `open` method.

Comment: That doesn't change anything :(

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use jquery mobile for the popup
first create a link with data-rel popup and href pointing to the id of the container containing the pop element. the div should have data-role popup

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
example
<a href="#pop" data-rel="popup>click me</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="pop">
... pop up elements go here ...
</div>
```